# JFrame Background Colors Not Showing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

Alright,
I'm not very familiar with the awt api so this is pretty new stuff to me. I have these methods running from my main class to create my jframe. Under my createframe method the background color does not seem to be applied to the frame. Any help?

Here's my frame class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FrameClass {

        JFrame frame;

        public FrameClass(String framename) {
                frame = new JFrame(framename);
        }

        public void CreateFrame() {
            Color c = new Color(0,255,0);
            Container con = frame.getContentPane();
            con.setBackground(c);
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
                frame.setSize(400, 250); // Set the JFrame size when it is on the login screen
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the JFrame

                /* Display the frame */
                frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void AddPanel() {
                JPanel ButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
                ButtonsPanel.setVisible(true);
                frame.add(ButtonsPanel);
        }
}
```

And here's my main class

```
public class Admin {

    public static FrameClass FrameObject = new FrameClass("ITWebKit Admin Panel");
    public static Database DatabaseObject = new Database();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FrameObject.CreateFrame();
        FrameObject.AddPanel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ButtonsPanel` is covering up the frame's content pane (of which you set the background to). You can either set the `ButtonsPanel`'s `opaque` property to `false` or set the background to the `ButtonsPanel` instead.

**Why this happens**

The content pane by default has a `BorderLayout`. The `BorderLayout` will stretch the `ButtonPanel` to fit it's size. If you were to to change the layout manager of the content pane/frame to FlowLayout (which will *not* stretch the panel), you will see the background.

**Other Notes:**

- `FrameObject.CreateFrame(); FrameObject.AddPanel();`. This will set the frame visible *before* adding the components. Generally you want to add the components, *then* set the frame visible.
- Follow Java naming convention. Method name and variable names begin with lower case letters.
- Swing programs should be started on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)